# ServiceStack4+LLBLGen4.2: Templates will not compile 'ServiceHost' is undefined

Tags: rest, servicestack, servicehost

We are a licensed user of ServiceStack and I am using the latest version.  I've created an LLBLGen project and added the latest ServiceStack LLBLGen templates.  I am able to generate the LLBLGen projects, but the XXXXProject.Services class library fails to compile:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'ServiceHost' does not exist in the namespace 'ServiceStack' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\PROJECTS\ServiceStack\XXXXService\XXXXService.ServiceModel\DAL\ServiceGeneric\Validators\VendorValidator.cs

Are the templates compatible with ServiceStack v4?  If not, do you know when they will be compatible or what I need to change to make them work with the latest version of ServiceStack?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Have you tried to post this question at LLBLGen forums? Also you need to post more info (i.e. LLBLGen version, the process to reproduce your issue, etc.) Ref: http://www.llblgen.com/TinyForum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=7725

Comment: Another useful link to get answers about this: http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2012/12/12/service-based-data-adapter-for-llblgen-entities-using-servicestack/   and    http://www.llblgen.com/TinyForum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=21737&StartAtMessage=0&#122527